# Send mail from iPhone app without using user interaction iOS5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, sendmail

Am trying to send a mail to recipient from iPhone app without user's interaction. I have tried `MFMailComposeViewController`, but it appear in an app. I don't want to show anything to the user, if they just tapped the '`Send Mail`'  button the mail automatically send to the recipient with body of the message. I also tried `SKPSMTPMessage` in my project, it is required Username and password but, i don't know the recipient login credentials how can i use this? And also i tried to add body of the mail in SKPSMTPMessage. I failed in this? Can anyone briefly suggest your great ideas? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well that may not be possible I assume.

Comment: Thank you Anonymous. There is any alternative way to send mail without user interaction? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible..
Even if there is a way..you will be 100 % rejected by the app store..as your app can send spam on behalf of user..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that SKPSMTPMessage does what you're looking for, you would just need the user to enter in the required details for their personal mail server, either each time you send an email OR in their account preferences or settings or something of that sort, similar to the Mail Settings built into the OS.