# Is it true that iOS app can't send mail without user intervention?

Tags: email, ios5

I want to make my app send an email, but without the user having to push a `send` button. The idea is that the user generates content on his phone and that content is automagically sent to his mailbox (as an attached file!) - so it's not like I'm doing anything covert or spammy.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441639/send-mail-from-iphone-app-without-using-user-interaction-ios5) seems to say that there's no way around that `send` button, or is there? What about that `SKPSMTPMessage` function? Could I provide my own SMTP information for that, and achieve my desired no-button email sending? Does it support attachments?

Comment: I would imagine that no, you cannot do that.  The potential for abuse there would be too high for Apple to ever allow that.

Comment: Take a moment and think about why this is true; and then why *your* app should be trusted not to abuse that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If iOS doesn't allow this, you could create a web service that accepts your content and then sends it.  EDIT: You'll still have to deal with credentials -- after all, you don't want to create a service that can be used by a spammer.

Comment: I _am_ doing a workaround based on a web service. But I wasn't asking for alternatives - I was trying to get confirmation that I really can't send fully automatic email.